# MKAnnotation pin color update

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

In my app I am displaying a tableview which contains result of searched user from database. Now in that tableview there is one button by clicking on that user can see location of all searched users in map.when user first click on button he will be able to see all user's location with green color pin. I am displaying map in half part of view. Now When user select any particular searched user from table I want to change color of that user's pin.And if user select any other user from table previous selected user's pin color should be changed to as it was before.
I have tried this:

```
- (void)selectAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation animated:(BOOL)animated{
    MKPinAnnotationView *chng=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
    chng.pinColor=MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    NSLog(@"========>selected");
 }
```

And I am calling this method when user select particular user from table.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D CurrentCoordinateSingleUser;
CurrentCoordinateSingleUser.latitude=[[singleUserPin objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
CurrentCoordinateSingleUser.longitude=[[singleUserPin objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
MapObjects   *map1=[[MapObjects alloc]initwithCoordinate:CurrentCoordinateSingleUser title:[singleUserPin objectAtIndex:0] subtitle:Nil];

[userMap addAnnotation:map1];
for (id<MKAnnotation> currentAnnotation in userMap.annotations) {       
    if ([currentAnnotation isEqual:annotationToSelect]) {
        [userMap selectAnnotation:currentAnnotation animated:FALSE];
    }
}
```

But here `selectAnnotation` is not working.

UPDATE::

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;


    static NSString *identifier = @"myAnnotation";
    MKPinAnnotationView * annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[userMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if([annotation isEqual:map1]){
        annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;

    }
    else {
        if (!annotationView)
        {

            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
//            if(fromSelectedTab==TRUE){
//            annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
//            annotationView.animatesDrop = NO;
//            fromSelectedTab=FALSE;
//            }
//            else{
            annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
            annotationView.animatesDrop = NO;
//            }
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

                // annotationView.dr
        }
        else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }
    }
    //annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    return annotationView;
}
```

MapObjects.h:

```
@interface MapObjects : NSObject<MKMapViewDelegate,MKAnnotation>
{
    NSString *title,*subtitle;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
}
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *title;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *subtitle;
@property(nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
-(MapObjects *)initwithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate title:(NSString    *)title subtitle:(NSString *)subtitle;

@end
```

Comment: What class is the selectAnnotation method in?  It creates a _new local_ view that's not used anywhere and disappears when the method ends.  In the code that's called "when user select particular user from table", why does it do add annotation (aren't all the annotations already on the map)?  What is annotationToSelect?

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation;
```

instead of creating a new `MKPinAnnotationView`. Or if it's in purpose you have to add somewhere the new `annotation` in your map.

Hope that will help

Comment: but how to detect annotation in which I want to make change

Answer (score 0):

You should override MKMapiew method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

       static NSString *identifier = @"PinAnnotation";
       // map1 should be visible in method context  
       if ([annotation isEqual:map1]) {
           MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnotation = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
           pinAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;// or any you want
           return pinAnnotation;
       }
       return nil;
}
```

There you can determine specified annotation and set it desired color.

Comment: how to determine that annotation

Comment: I just want to know that only

Comment: you said that you have a lot of users, and just want to mark selected user with no-green color, others in green color. Right?

Comment: yes.....and if user select another user from tableview then that result should get according color...

Comment: Don't forget to mark question as solved and mark my answer useful +1.

Answer (score 0):

in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // There you should have selected "user" object and "users" array

    ...

    // _annotations is declared in header
    _annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    for (UserObj *obj in users) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0.f, 0.f);
        coordinate.latitude = obj.latitude;
        coordinate.longitude = obj.longitude;
        MapObjects *userAnnotation = [[MapObjects alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate title:obj.name subtitle:nil];
        [map addAnnotation:userAnnotation];
        [_annotations addObject:userAnnotation];
    }

    ...
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKPinAnnotationView *)view {
    view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKPinAnnotationView *)view {        
    view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    static NSString *identifier = @"PinAnnotation";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnotation = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if(!pinAnnotation) {
        pinAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    pinAnnotation.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;

    return pinAnnotation;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // You should keep your annotation objects in some array too because map.annotations won't return annotation in order that we need
    // After you add annotation to map, add them to NSMutableArray too, [_annotations addObject:userAnnotation];
    MapObjects annotation = _annotations[indexPath.row];// not sure that it return that exact annotation
    [map selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: MapObjects is a custom class, title I saw in init method. Just make title as property.

Comment: oknow I can access that....but I got this error 
No visible interface for mapobjects declares selector isEqualtoString

Comment: I have just gave retain attribute to it thats why it is not visible there...but now i got error which i have mentioned in comment

Comment: What type is property title of MapObjects? Not NSString?

Comment: Try this ((MapObjects *)annotation).title

Comment: the condition we are checking will always true...because I am displaying user name to annotationview title...so it is displaying now all pin in red

Comment: Strange, why users have the same names? Just create another field id for annotation then, and pass user id then. And compare annotation.id and user.id

Comment: no you are getting in wrong way....first time when I am loading map...at that time this method will also call at that time what happen I am passing annotations array to map. SO now when this method will call ....annotation title will be same as user.name

Comment: ok and when user select any user from tableview at that time what will be happen?

Comment: shoul i have to call anu method in tableview didselectrow at indexpath method?

Comment: means....how to tell that this pin is selected?? For that should i have to call selectAnnotation method?

Comment: how to make that pin selected?

Comment: Don't forget to mark question as solved and mark my answer useful +1.

Comment: You can't select two or more pin at the same time. Second selection always deselects first one. And you can't just change color of pin, only through map delegate methods, and they don't allow you to select more than one pin.